# Помогите понять тестовое задание на php

Tags: php, laravel

Короче прислали тестовое задание на Laravel, в принципе все понятно, за исключением 4го пункта.
Никак не могу понять, вот через регу создаём пользователя для проверки его сообщений, а дальше в смысле закрыть страницу от всех дальнейших переходов? Я так понял, что каждый юзер должен иметь доступ только к своим сообщениям, а не к сообщениям других юзеров, так что ли?

1. Сделай четыре страницы: страница регистрации пользователя, страница с формой для ввода данных, страница с выводом данных, закрытая авторизацией и главная страница со ссылками на все остальные страницы, например в виде удобного меню
2. Кроме стандартного класса регистрации сделай класс с двумя методами. Логику методов мы видим такой: на одной странице будет форма отправки сообщений, которые должны сохраняться в бд. На второй - вывод сообщений с информацией о временем их создания.
3. Закрой страницу вывода сообщений авторизацией
4. Форма с регистрацией должна единожды создавать только одного пользователя в бд, для проверки вывода сообщений. После регистрации первого пользователя, закрывай страницу регистрации от всех дальнейших переходов. У пользователя должен быть доступ к странице вывода.

Comment: Лучше спросить у того, кто составлял это задание. Наверное, хотят чтобы после регистрации была скрытая авторизация, и пользователь не смог зайти на страницу регистрации заново, и был перенаправлен на страницу со списком сообщений при попытке перехода на нее. Но это не точно.

Comment: Если что-то непонятно в задании, то надо обратиться с вопросом к непосредственно задание выдавшему, а не к каким-то левым чувакам на сайте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В 4 пункте видимо описано как мне кажется 2 варианта:

1. Это просто на странице регистрации, после регистрации нечего не происходит и выводится большое сообщение об успешной регистрации, и если авторизован то к ней не должно быть доступа
2. Задание честно написано на коленке, стоит задуматься о месте работы :)

Comment: `Задание честно написано на коленке` - это не баг, это фишка! Работодатель может таким способом проверяет, спросит ТС у него, или сделает неправильно, и пойдет переделывать. Так и работать будет, молча, терпя и переделывая. А такие не нужны